# Spring - List required headers for each controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

We have a requirement to list all request mappings with their parameters and their headers (both mandatory and optional).

I did manage to log all the request mappings with their parameters [like this](https://gist.github.com/amaralani/2e310d0f2855c8f0a6c50724e5cab03a).

But how can I have a list of what headers are processed for any address?

I think there might be some way to read this information from the configurations (preferably on the runtime).

For example, I want the result to indicate that for a request to `/app/foo` the required headers are `Content-type`, `Cookie`, and `referer`. But for `/app/bar` the only required header is `Content-type`.

Comment: Can Swagger assist you?

Comment: @riorio It's a Spring project with Spring Security and Spring MVC, not a Spring Boot. Unfortunately, the most support for Swagger and OpenAPI is for Boot and requires some dependencies that we do not want to add to our project.

Comment: You can use a spring filter

Comment: @OctavianR. I think that filter would log the data when the request is being received, right? I want to have them all as soon as the application starts. Think of it as a kind of documentation. A customized swagger.

Comment: @AmirM then swagger documentation is the response.